# postfix cannot send emails

Tags: centos, php, postfix

I recently migrated some sites from my old server to a new one with the same configuration on DigitalOcean.

The sites working great except for the php mail() function that isn't sending emails.

The php configuration is the same of the old server, and I can't see where the problem is.

The postfix configuration is:

```
$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = MY_DOMAIN
myhostname = MY_DOMAIN
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

And when a make a test, the maillog output is:

```
Jun  3 16:43:18 tori postfix/pickup[3648]: 7F6D8480E73: uid=500 from=<santiago@gmail.com>
Jun  3 16:43:18 tori postfix/cleanup[4033]: 7F6D8480E73: message-id=<20150603204318.7F6D8480E73@MY_DOMAIN>
Jun  3 16:43:18 tori postfix/qmgr[3649]: 7F6D8480E73: from=<santiago@gmail.com>, size=360, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  3 16:43:18 tori postfix/error[3992]: 7F6D8480E73: to=<santiago@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to aspmx5.googlemail.com[74.125.205.27]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After talk with my server provider (DigitalOcean), I found that they was blocking the outgoing emails from my server.

The problem is solved.

Thanks.